# How can I extract still frames from an MPEG video with Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, video, hd-video

I have a MPEG video of high quality. I want to open the video with photoshop so that I could extract some still images. But when I open it, I got an error `could not complete your request because the video file could not be opened`.

Does anyone know some workaround?

It seems that we can open MP4 or M4V video with photoshop, but I really don't want to convert my video because I am afraid of loss of quality.

Comment: Before voting to close this question as a purely video-related question, please consider that [extracting video frames](http://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=extract+video+frames) is sometimes suggested as a workaround for some still photography problems, e.g. long shutter delay, short maximum exposure time or low frame rate.

Comment: Do you need to do it with Photoshop, or are you just looking to solve the image extraction problem and happen to have Photoshop at hand?

Comment: @mattdm I want to extract some images from this video, and I have already Photoshop... Is there other way to extract high quality images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [supported formats list](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/supported-file-formats-photoshop-cs6.html) and [similar experience of other users](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4700873),  you'll need an Adobe-supplied codec (e.g. from Adobe Premiere Pro) to open MPEG-2 files with Photoshop CS6 or newer; older versions relied on QuickTime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), a cross-platform command-line tool, to extract the frames you want as PNG files, which you can then open in Photoshop.

From the [documention](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video), there are several approaches you can take. One would be to open a console (the ffmpeg executable must be in your PATH) and run the command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:14.435 -vframes 1 out.png
```

Where `input.mp4` is the filename for the video you want to extract from, and `00:00:14.435` identifies the time of the frame you want to extract.

Or, you could extract all frames this way:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f image2 input.mp4_fr%7d.png
```

Where `%7d` will number each frame using 7 digits, padding the front of the number with zeros as necessary.